# Does Kotlin have an equivalent to Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals in Swift?

Tags: kotlin, option-type, unwrap

Implicitly unwrapped optionals are a useful feature of Swift for things like UI elements that are not assigned during a class's constructor, but can be safely be assumed to be non-null for the majority of functions (as they will have been assigned in a viewDidLoad).

eg.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView : UITextView!
```

Is there an equivalent for Kotlin, or a workaround that achieves the same effect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`lateinit var` may be a suitable solution. Kotlin just assumes they are not null.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties